# Pandas faster implementation of date calculation on every row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, including `analysis_date` (datetime), and `forecast_hour` (int). I want to add a new column called `total_hours`, which is the sum of the hour component of `analysis_date` plus the corresponding `forecast_hour` in that row. Here's a visual example:

original dataframe:

```
analysis_date | forecast_hour
12-2-19-05    | 3
12-2-19-06    | 3
12-2-19-07    | 3
12-2-19-08    | 3
```

dataframe after calculation:

```
analysis_date | forecast_hour | total_hours
12-2-19-05    | 3             | 8
12-2-19-06    | 3             | 9
12-2-19-07    | 3             | 10
12-2-19-08    | 3             | 11
```

Here is the current logic that does what I want:

```
df['total_hours'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.analysis_date.hour + row.forecast_hours_out, axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, this is too slow for my application, it takes around 15 seconds for a dataframe with a few hundred thousand entries. I have tried using the [swifter](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter) library, but unfortunately, it took approximately as long (if not longer) than my current implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` is slow because it is not vectorized.  This should do what you want (assuming `df['analysis_date']` is a [`datetime64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)):

```
df['total_hours'] = df['analysis_date'].dt.hour + df['forecast_hour']
```

Comment: Similar/related question: is it possible for me to add the hours to the analysis_date? something along the hours of `df['analysis_date'].dt+ timedelta(hours=df['forecast_hour'])` where the output is a datetime64?

Comment: @P.V. Yep, [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html#pandas-to-timedelta) is what you are looking for.  `df['analysis_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['forecast_hour'], unit='hours')`